# Many to Many relation ship entity double indirect foreign key problem

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relationship, data-modeling

i have follow relationship between my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `class`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'first, second, etc (grade)',
  `province` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `class_province`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `class` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `province` int(0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_nm_class`(`class`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_nm_province`(`province`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_nm_class` FOREIGN KEY (`class`) REFERENCES `class` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_nm_province` FOREIGN KEY (`province`) REFERENCES `province` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `class_schooltype`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `class` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `schooltype` int(0) NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_nm_schooltype`(`class`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_nm_classschooltype` FOREIGN KEY (`class`) REFERENCES `class` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_nm_schooltype` FOREIGN KEY (`class`) REFERENCES `school_type` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `country`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `province`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` int(0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_province_country`(`country`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_province_country` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `school_type`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` int(0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_schooltype_country`(`country`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_schooltype_country` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

My problem is that now class can have both a province (which has country A) and a schooltype which could have country B. That should not be possible.
What may i change?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please just give DDL--relation(ship)/table names & columns & FK constraints--table & column list referencing table & column list, and CKs would show the cardinalities. You still don't clearly explain what you think the problem is. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. However this seems like a certain faq. But one can't (re)search properly without many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal-there's none here. The declarative solution is (tersely) CPS(c,p,s), CP(c,p), PS(p,s) & FKs (c,p) & (p,s).

Comment: okay, i have updated it

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Can you please help me? I am still struggling :(

Comment: I told you the answer, "CPS(c,p,s), CP(c,p), PS(p,s) & FKs (c,p) & (p,s)". You need to declare column sets that are referenced by FKs as UNIQUE or PK. If you want tables to agree in pairs of values you need the pair in the tables. You need to a have a chain of FKs from one to the other. PS You still aren't making clear generic statements of the problem, so you can't (re)search anything. "Use enough words [...]" PS Please don't include unnecessary info.